# adding enum to ATL DLL in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I created c++ project in VS2010 as follows:
1 - new project -> Visual c++ -> ATL -> ATl Project -> selected DLL. 
2 - right click on the created project -> add -> class -> ATL -> ATL Simple Object . Then I wrote all required information. 
3 - then I went to Class View wizard -> right click on the interface -> add method or property.

all this allows me to add a method or property to the interface. but How can I add enum to the interface?

I created ATL DLL project that will be called by C#/ VB. I am trying to add a read only object to the interface that provides the status of the dll's operation. So I thought of adding enum. is there a better way?

thanks for any help

Comment: Sometimes you just need to use old good keyboard just to go and type manually. Open the .h file for you class and type: enum MyEnum{value1, value2, value3}

Comment: I already done this. But I am creating a DLL, and this enum should be readable by whoever is loading it (e.g. vb/c#). USING YOU SUGGESTION WILL NOT MAKE IT READABLE (VB/ C# can't read it). It will make it readable in C++ only. In VB/C#, I only can find all methods that I added to the Interface.

Comment: All you need to add an entry to the MIDL for the COM interface. There is a type for enum as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info, I added the following line "[id(24)] HRESULT Status([out, retval] ULONG* eStatus); but I am getting the following error " >c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(1994): error C2259: 'ATL::CComObject<Base>' : cannot instantiate abstract class      with [Base=CAirPlaneII ]  due to following members:'HRESULT IAirPlaneII::Status(ULONG *)' : is abstract c:\work\airplaneii_i.h(296) : see declaration of 'IAirPlaneII::Status'

Comment: any idea why it is getting me this error?

Comment: Have you implemented the new method?

Comment: @Chas: Thanks for you help, I found how to do it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682501/how-to-specify-user-defined-type-parameters-in-com-interface-definition

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the enum manually in the IDL by using the same syntax as in C++:

```
enum MyEnum
{
  VAL1,
  VAL2,
  ...
};
```

When using it as an argument type you need to put the keyword "enum" in front of your Enum's name:

```
[propget] HRESULT MyProp([out, retval] enum MyEnum* pVal);
```

In the C++ header/source do not use "enum" in front of MyEnum.